# Parallels in Sotah 11a and Shabbat 33b

Tags: sources-mekorot, reward-punishment, maseches-shabbos, tractate-sotah

I noticed yesterday that there are some similarities between the story brought in Sotah 11a and the one in Shabbat 33b. In [Sotah 11a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sotah.11a.12-13?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) it says:

> "Rabbi Ḥiyya bar Abba says that Rabbi Simai says: Three noteworthy people were consulted by Pharaoh in that counsel where Pharaoh questioned what should be done with the Jewish people. They were Balaam, and Job, and Yitro. Rabbi Ḥiyya bar Abba teaches what occurred to each of them: Balaam, who advised Pharaoh to kill all sons born to the Jewish people, was punished by being killed in the war with Midian (see Numbers 31:8). Job, who was silent and neither advised nor protested, was punished by suffering, as detailed in the eponymous book in the Bible. Yitro, who ran away as a sign of protest, merited that some of his children’s children sat in the Sanhedrin in the Chamber of Hewn Stone, as it is stated: “And the families of scribes who dwelt at Jabez, Tirathites, Shimeathites, and Sucathites, these were the Kenites who descended from Hammath, the father of the house of Rechab” (I Chronicles 2:55). And it is written: “The children of the Kenite, Moses’ father-in-law” (Judges 1:16)."

While in [Shabbat 33b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.33b.5?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it says:

> "The Gemara asks: And why did they call him head of the speakers in every place? The Gemara relates that this resulted due to an incident that took place when Rabbi Yehuda and Rabbi Yosei and Rabbi Shimon were sitting, and Yehuda, son of converts, sat beside them. Rabbi Yehuda opened and said: How pleasant are the actions of this nation, the Romans, as they established marketplaces, established bridges, and established bathhouses. Rabbi Yosei was silent. Rabbi Shimon ben Yoḥai responded and said: Everything that they established, they established only for their own purposes. They established marketplaces, to place prostitutes in them; bathhouses, to pamper themselves; and bridges, to collect taxes from all who pass over them. Yehuda, son of converts, went and related their statements to his household, and those statements continued to spread until they were heard by the monarchy. They ruled and said: Yehuda, who elevated the Roman regime, shall be elevated and appointed as head of the Sages, the head of the speakers in every place. Yosei, who remained silent, shall be exiled from his home in Judea as punishment, and sent to the city of Tzippori in the Galilee. And Shimon, who denounced the government, shall be killed."

In both stories, there's a discussion between three wise men: One suggests a bad thing, one says nothing and one suggests a good thing. Each receives a punishment or a reward according to what he said/did. In Sotah, the matter at hand is what should be done to Bnei Yisrael. The person who pushed for negative action against them is punished while the person who rejected this is rewarded. The silent one receives a middle-of-the-road punishment. In Shabbat, the story is reversed: The matter at hand is what do the sages think about the Romans. The person who praised them is rewarded while the person who rejected them and attacked them is punished. But here as well, the silent one receives a middle-of-the-road punishment.

Has the connection been made by anyone? Any sources discussing this?

Comment: There is a newer Ein Yackov that came out with a Pirush called "Mizeh Umizeh" who mentions a connection between the 2 Gemaras      https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=60147&st=&pgnum=102